# Как осуществить ввод списка с отступом от края

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, a, b, n;
    unsigned char ch1, ch2;
    char str_spisok[29][19], str[19];
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");


    cout << "Введите число фамилий в списке (29 или меньше): ";              
 //количесво фамилий 29 или меньше.
    cin >> n;                                                                
  //29 отвечает 30 фамилиям

    cout << "\t"<<" Вводим список класса: \n";
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)  gets(str_spisok[i]);
      for (a=1;a<n;a++)
        for (b=n;b>=a;b--){
          ch1=str_spisok[b-1][0];
         ch2=str_spisok[b][0];
         if (ch1>ch2){
                      strcpy(str,str_spisok[b-1]);
                      strcpy(str_spisok[b-1],str_spisok[b]);
                      strcpy(str_spisok[b],str);
                      }
         }

 cout << "\t  Список отсортирован:\n ";
 for (i=0;i<=n;i++) cout <<"  \t"<< str_spisok[i]<< "\n";

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Как сделать отступ от края при вводе фамилии?

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что вы имеете в виду. Вы хотите, чтобы при вводе с клавиатуры каждой строки курсор находился не в первой (как обычно бывает после нажатия на ENTER) позиции строки а в заданной (скажем, 10-й)?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Тогда печатайте в цикле ввода перед `gets` (только замените его на fgets) нужное число пробелов.

Comment: А в каком кокретно место вставлять пробелы перед gets, я уже все препробовал, везде появляется ошибка при компиляции.

Comment: Вот здесь `for (i=0;i<n;i++) { cout << "   ...."; gets(str_spisok[i]);}`, естественно

Comment: Все получилось. Вот только после " Вводим список класса:" первая фамилия пробивается в два раза дальше, чем вторая

Comment: Это видимо какая-то ерунда с реализацией крестов в винде. Попробуйте всюду сделать ввод-вывод через сишные функции (fscanf/fgets/fputs/fflush). Должно заработать

Comment: Пробовал,  та же история

Comment: Ну, не знаю. Впрочем, перед чтением фамилий еще надо прочесть оставшиеся во входном потоке после `cin >> n;` символы конца строки. Если надо, могу попробовать у себя.

Comment: Буду очень признателен, не люблю не понятки, хочется , что все работало четко

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::string > vs(29);
std::string s;
size_t i = vs.size();
while ( std::cin >> s && i--) {       
    vs.emplace_back(s);
}
```

как хотите так и вводите - фамилии будут в вашем векторе

Comment: На счет  fgets понял, не понял куда всунуть нужное число пробелов. Можно, наверное, вставить "\t"

Comment: вы хотите вводить фамилии через пробелы?

Comment: Сделал всавку   for (i=0;i<n;i++) { cout << " ...."; gets(str_spisok[i]);}  Все получилось. Вот только после " Вводим список класса:" первая фамилия пробивается в два раза дальше, чем вторая

Answer (score 0):

Вот почти ваша программа.
Я просто оставил в ней все относящееся к вводу-выводу данных, добавил вычитывание символов, оставшихся после ввода количества фамилий, заменил `gets()` на С++-ный ввод строки `.getline()` и выбросил "сортировку" (она в таком виде все равно не работает, но это уж вы сами сделайте)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, a, n;
  char str_spisok[29][19];

  cout << "Введите число фамилий в списке (29 или меньше): ";
  //количесво фамилий 29 или меньше.
  cin >> n;
  while ((a = cin.get()) != '\n')
    if (a == EOF)
      exit(1);

  cout << "\t"<<" Вводим список класса: \n";
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)  {
    cout << "\t ";
    cin.getline(str_spisok[i], 19);
    if (cin.eof())
      exit(1);
  }


  cout << "\t  Список отсортирован:\n ";
  for (i=0;i<n;i++) cout <<"  \t"<< str_spisok[i]<< "\n";

  //  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Проверка в Linux:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ t1.cpp -Wall && ./a.out
Введите число фамилий в списке (29 или меньше): 3
     Вводим список класса: 
     Иванов
     Петров
     Sidorov
      Список отсортирован:
    Иванов
    Петров
    Sidorov
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Как видите с отступами все нормально.

В Win-7 (MinGW и окошко консоли) я тоже попробовал и с печатью отступов
 также нет проблем.

Comment: Не плохо бы в exit  тоже  константу использовать - EXIT_FAILURE.